# Cancel touches events on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a list on images in a Pivot control. If you touch an image, it navigates to another view. If if flick through a new pivot and touch the image meanwhile, it navigates.

I noticed the Facebook app or the native photo albums don't have this bug.

Any idea ?

edit: the code :

```
                            Image img = new Image();
                            Delay.LowProfileImageLoader.SetUriSource(img, new Uri(adViewModel.Photos[k].ThbUrl));
                            img.Width = 150;
                            img.Tag = k;
                            img.Height = 150;
                            img.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(launch_Diapo);
                            Grid.SetRow(img, i);
                            Grid.SetColumn(img, j);

                            PhotosGrid.Children.Add(img);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can show your code we can probably provide a more specific answer.

However:

I'm guessing you're using `MouseButtonLeftDown` or similar to detect the touching of the image. Rather than this, use the `Tap` gesture from the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034). This should prevent the issue you're having.

There is a possible alternative to disable the pivot gesture while you're touching the image, but depending on how you're using the image within the pivotItem this may end up preventing proper pivot navigation.

You can add the `Tap` event in code like this:

```
var gl = GestureService.GetGestureListener(img);

gl.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(gl_Tap);
```

and the handler would be something like this. (but actually doing something useful-obviously.)

```
void gl_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("tapped");
}
```

Comment: I added my code, it's probably the MouseButtonLeftDown since I don't use tap. How can I use tap programmatically ? I saw example with xaml only. I need to create a GestureListener, but how can I bind it to my image ?

Answer (score 0):

Even I had a similar problem . What i did is ,check for `MouseButtonLeftDown` position and `MouseButtonLeftUp` position .If they are Equal navigate else do nothing .I will paste the code below.

```
Point temp;

void img_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    temp = e.GetPosition(null);
}

void img_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = e.GetPosition(null);
    if (point == temp)
    {
       this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(...));
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to add some tolerance for a small amount of movement if doing this. Otherwise you could end up missing what hte user thought was a tap but was actually a *very* small swipe.